# Extracting negative and positive floats from a string read from a file

Tags: java

I've been having issues on this for some time now, and I'm completely lost.
The program Im trying to create is for school, and its simply a bank account, with their expenses and deposits. Im having trouble trying to extract the positive and negative numbers from the file. When I do "[^0-9]" it works fine but when I try using a pattern for negative numbers, the code doesnt work.

Here it is

```
package recursionReadFile;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class bankAccount {

public static float[] bankTransactionsValues (int lines)throws IOException{
        
        //Create a object reader
        BufferedReader readFile;
        readFile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("D:\\Garis\\Desktop\\Programs\\recursionReadFile\\src\\recursionReadFile\\BankAccount.txt"));
        
   
      
        
        
        //Array that holds all transactions values
        float [] totalTransactionsValues = new float[lines];
        //For loop that reads the notepad to the array
        for (int index = 0 ; index < totalTransactionsValues.length ;index++)
        {   //Read the file onto to the array
            String currentTransAction = readFile.readLine().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
            totalTransactionsValues [index] = Float.parseFloat(currentTransAction);
        }
        readFile.close();//end of the reading
        //Return array of the strings with time slots
        return totalTransactionsValues;
    }

public static String[] bankTransactions (int lines)throws IOException{
    
    //Create a object reader
    BufferedReader readFile;
    readFile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("D:\\Garis\\Desktop\\Programs\\recursionReadFile\\src\\recursionReadFile\\BankAccount.txt"));
 
  
    
    //Array that holds all transactions values
    String [] totalTransactions = new String[lines];
    //For loop that reads the notepad to the array
    for (int index = 0 ; index < totalTransactions.length ;index++)
    {   //Read the file onto to the array
        totalTransactions [index] = readFile.readLine();
    }
    
    readFile.close();//end of the reading
    //Return array of the strings with time slots
    return totalTransactions;
}

public static int numberOfTransactions() throws IOException{
    //Create a object reader
        BufferedReader readFile;
        readFile = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("D:\\Garis\\Desktop\\Programs\\recursionReadFile\\src\\recursionReadFile\\BankAccount.txt"));
        
        //Count the number of lines
        int lines = 0; 
        
        //For loop that contiues if there is a non empty space in the file
        while (readFile.readLine() != null) {
            //Increase the variable count
            lines++;
        }
        readFile.close();
      
        return lines;
}

    



    
    
    public static String [] sortLowToHigh(String [] transactionValues) {

        
         for (int index = 1 ; index < transactionValues.length ; index++)
            {
                String item = transactionValues[index];
                float itemValue =  Float.parseFloat(item.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
                
                int toPlace = index;
                
                while (toPlace > 0 &&  itemValue < Float.parseFloat(transactionValues[toPlace - 1].replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")) )
                {
                    transactionValues [toPlace] = transactionValues [toPlace - 1];
                    toPlace--;
                }//while
                transactionValues [toPlace] = item;
             }//for index
      
         
         return transactionValues;
        
    }
    
    
    public static String[] sortHighToLow(String [] transactionValues) {

        for (int index = 1; index < transactionValues.length; index++) {
            String item = transactionValues[index];
            
            int toPlace = index;
            while (toPlace > 0 && Float.parseFloat(item)  >  Float.parseFloat(transactionValues[toPlace - 1])) { 
                transactionValues[toPlace] = transactionValues[toPlace - 1];
                toPlace--;
            }
            transactionValues[toPlace] = item;
        }

        return transactionValues;
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    public static void introduction() throws IOException {
        int lines = numberOfTransactions();     
        
    
        String [] transactions = bankTransactions(lines);
        

        
        transactions = sortLowToHigh(transactions);
        
        for (int index =0;index< transactions.length; index++){
            
            
            System.out.println(transactions[index]);
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        
    introduction();
        
        
        
    }

}
```

This is the error message I am getting.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-50.00  Dining out"
at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
at java.base/java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:555)
at recursionReadFile/recursionReadFile.bankAccount.sortLowToHigh(bankAccount.java:85)
at recursionReadFile/recursionReadFile.bankAccount.introduction(bankAccount.java:132)
at recursionReadFile/recursionReadFile.bankAccount.main(bankAccount.java:149)

And here is the text file

````
-100.00  Groceries
-50.00  Dining out
-200.00  Rent payment
-75.00  Utility bill
-30.00  Gasoline
-150.00  Shopping
-80.00  Internet bill
-60.00  Entertainment
-100.00  Medical expenses
-50.00  Gym membership
1,000.00  Salary
200.00  Freelance work payment
300.00  Tax refund
150.00  Gift from a family member
500.00  Reimbursement from insurance
100.00  Bonus
250.00  Cashback rewards
400.00  Investment dividend
75.00  Sale of a personal item
150.00  Rental income```
````

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem. If I print the value of `"-50.00 Dining out".replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")` it is `5000`. Are you sure that the code in your question is the code you're running?

Answer (score 0):

Parse the lines using the following code:

```
// Sample line: "-50.00  Dining out"
String[] parts = line.split(" ");
// First part is the expense/deposit value
double expense = parseDouble(parts[0]);
// Now get the text parts
String category = "";
for (int i = 1; i < parts.length; i++) {
    category += " " + parts[i];
}
category = category.trim();
```

EDIT: I just realized that there are commas in some double values and you should use the following method to parse these values gracefully:

```
private static double parseDouble(String strNumber) throws ParseException{
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    Number number = format.parse(strNumber);
    return number.doubleValue();
}
```

To display/format the double values with two decimal places:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.println("expense: " + decimalFormat.format(expense));
```

Comment: Okay so I tried using the code given.  However, I'm getting an error message saying, "Unparseable number: "-". I'd like to keep the negative sign as well, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Update, it worked!!! I just forgot the space .split(""). One more question, how can I have the number be two decimal places, for example, -50.00?

Comment: The `parseDouble()` method already handles the double value regardless of decimal places.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. Do you want to *display* the numbers with 2 decimal places?

Comment: yea two decimal places, I find that everything else you provided was exactly what i wanted, however, I would like to store the expense with two decimal places. Thank you so much for helping

Comment: I have just edited my answer. Please look at the end of the answer.